# Unable to apply "flex justify content space between" on Odoo website because of hidden ::after element

Tags: html, css, sass, odoo, owl-carousel

I'm trying to arrange some elements with "flex justify content space between" but because there is an ::after element inside the div I get a margin at the right side that should not be there. Is there a way to get rid of this?

simplified html:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ::after
</div>
```

simplified scss:

```
div {
   display: flex;
   justify-content:  space-between;
   div {
   margin: auto;
   }
}
```

[Image of the result, without the :: after element the right purple part would not be there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlpE8.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the ":after" element? If it's possible you can add "position: absolute;", that way the element would be ignored.

Otherwise you can maybe add an extra wrapper, for example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "after";
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```